# List Comprehension in a dict.fromkeys(SetA, ...)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension

I want to generate a new dictionary using pre-existing information. Using `dict.fromkeys()` passing arguments such as a `set()` of `DictA.keys()` and the `DictA.values()`, but, here's what I'm stuck in:

```
NewDictFromKeys = dict.fromkeys(set(DictA.keys()), DictA.values())
```

But passing `DictA.values()` is logic that it will return this:

```
{'pnrdshfxgjltmqacbvuek': [10, 5, 14, 9, 7, 6, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 11, 13, 3],   'prktahjvqcgfsbuxdlemn': [10, 5, 14, 9, 7, 6, 1, 2, 4, 8, 12, 11, 13, 3], ...
 ... }
```

and so on.

The problem is: Assigning for each key a value that corresponds to itself. I mentioned List Comprehension because it might be one good solution, but how to apply is another problem.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `dict.fromkeys()` reuses the second argument for all values. You stored the *same list* as a reference over and over again.

Use a dict comprehension instead:

```
{k: DictA.values() for k in DictA}
```

The left-hand side key and value expressions in a dict comprehension are executed for every iteration. Each time `DictA.values()` is called again, producing a new list object.

Note that there is no need to call `set(DictA)` here, you can iterate over `DictA` *directly* for all the keys, and they are already unique (they have to be).

Comment: interesting Martijn, but how would it looks like on my code? Could you explain it?

Comment: @NiceGuy: Sorry, I am not certain I follow you. I gave you a sample already; `DictA` is your dictionary, the dict comprehension produces a new dictionary with the same keys as `DictA` and the values each the full list of values from `DictA`.

Comment: Martijn Pieters, I will try to pass to you the meaning in using set. In fact I have two dicts: DictA and DictB. From those dicts I create a new var for each to hold a set of their keys. After that I would make a Intersection between both sets like this: `Intersected = SetDictA & SetDictB`. The result of that intersection is what I need. Then I would pass to `dict.fromkeys(Intersected, "Comment: And then do some thinng here to assign the correspondent value to the keys in Intersected"`. That's why I used Set in the question above.

Comment: @NiceGuy: Right, you can use dictionary views for that (which are basically sets). `DictA.viewkeys() & DictB` gives you the intersection of keys.

Answer (score 0):

also consider using dict comprehension to modify the current dict like:

```
{k:v+data for k,v in DictA.items()}
```

or just:

```
d = {}
for k,v in DictA.items():
    d[k] = manipulate(v)
```